# Need to find attribute and click on it

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

I have element `newdevice`, with the following attribute `remove device from account`.

`newdevice` is unique, but a lot of same attributes.

[image]

Problem that I unable to perform click button.

```
WebElement newdevice = driver.findElement(By.linkText(devicename));
        if (newdevice.isDisplayed() && newdevice.isEnabled()) {
            newdevice.getAttribute("remove device from account");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            newdevice.click();
        }
```

So I expecting to find new element, if element is presence, then find attribute bellow element and click on it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  Also, edit your question to include the HTML instead of posting as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element with text as **remove device from account** within the element **newdevice** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *xpath 1*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td/strong[text()='newdevice']//following::td[3]//button[contains(@title, 'remove device')]"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath 2*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td/strong[text()='newdevice']//following::td//button[@title='remove device from account']"))).click();
  ```